# PHP Form Confirmation Parse Error

Tags: php, forms, post, confirmation, php-parse-error

I have some very simple PHP code that I'm using to confirm input from a form.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Unit 7 - Homework 5</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Contact us</h1>
        <table>
            <form method="POST" action="script.php">
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="First Name" id="fname"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Last Name" id="lname"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>E-mail:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="E-mail" id="email"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Comments</td>
                    <td><textarea rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Contact"> &nbsp; <input type="reset"></td>
                </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php print "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en\">
<head>
    <title>Form Confirmation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Congratulations, registration done!</h1>";
    $message = ";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $message .= $key . ":" .$value. "<br>\r\n";
    }

    print $message;
    print "<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form action=\"#\">
    <input type=\"button\" value=\"Back\" onclick=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>"
?>
```

The PHP code keeps producing an error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in <PHP path goes here> on line 10
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, although I feel I might have forgotten a semicolon.

Comment: see, syntax highlighting here shows EXACTLY where the error is. -1 because Syntax errors are very rarely good questions for stackoverflow: most of the times, at best, they're too localized to be a good question for our community.

Answer (score 3):

the PHP parser get confused by this:

$message = ";

replace with

$message = "";

Answer (score 1):

Apart from error `$message = ";` to `$message = "";` You are using `print` inside `print` to show message(`print $message`).

**Alternate Solution :-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Form Confirmation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Congratulations, registration done!</h1>
    <?php

    $message = '';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $message .= $key . ":" .$value. "<br>\r\n";
    }

    print $message;
    ?>
    <form action="#">
    <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wait, can I add the PHP code into the HTML and have only one file instead of two? I now PHP is a server-side scripting language but since this is just a homework assignment, the goal was to execute it locally.

Comment: No you can't add php code into HTML. It won't parse even code. All php code will display on your web page without any error.

Answer (score 0):

There you are:

```
$message = ";
```

Maybe it's :

```
$message = "";
```

Also, you don't need to declare it in this way, you can also:

```
$message;
```

Answer (score 0):

your only mistake is that you have put the text thjat you wanted php to print in double quotes, this means that php will evaluate it and see if it needs to process something with it. Instead you should have put it in single quote like this: ... ':' ...

Anything quoted in single quotes will be printed as-it-is, character by character.
Anything in double quotes will be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be

```
$message = "";
foreach ($_POST['somevalue'] as $key => $value) {
    $message .= $key . ":" .$value. "<br>\r\n";
}
```